# What is mean by an urban air ship app in android

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

hi friends sorry for asking a such a question here. i am going to do an app based on urban air ship. I do not know what it means.

What is mean by urban airship? What to be done here. Please help me with some useful blogs or own explanation friends.

Comment: Ask whomever asked you what the heck they mean instead.

Comment: Why -1, this is a perfectly technical valid question ?

Comment: Ever thought of reading the [documentation](http://urbanairship.com/docs/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Urban Airship is similar to Xtify and C2DM, in that it is a framework for pushing events to an Android application.